# Why would I be getting a setPriceSetID error?

Tags: contributions

I am getting the following error when I try to access the contributions of one specific contact record.  The error does not come up when accessing the contributions of other contact records.

TypeError: Argument 1 passed to CRM_Financial_BAO_Order::setPriceSetID() must be of the type int, null given, called in /var/www/emicrm/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Financial/BAO/Order.php on line 910 in CRM_Financial_BAO_Order->setPriceSetID() (line 471 of /var/www/emicrm/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Financial/BAO/Order.php).

We are using CiviCRM 5.51.1. and Drupal 7.91.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3150 for some possible ways this can happen and how to fix. Also it can come up with webform if you're using an old version of webform or the contribution was created by an old version of webform.